# Django wkhtmltopdf Errno 13 Permission denied

Tags: python, django, permissions, wkhtmltopdf

I have installed a package wkhtmltopdf, I did symlink `ln -s /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf.sh /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf`
I gave permissions: `chmod a + rx /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf.sh`
When I entered the command: `http://www.google.com output.pdf wkhtmltopdf` - it works.

But when you click on the button generates a document gets the error:

```
OSError at /app/my-document/51/
[Errno 13] Permission denied
```

Comment: Your web app server is most likely running as a different user

Comment: Are you sure about that command? Isn't is `./wkhtmltopdf http://www.google.com output.pdf` instead? You mention a button, but what does it do? Can you share the code and the full traceback?